# sed - include all found in between 2 pattern, except what's found between other pattern

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, xml

I have a sed pattern search as below:

```
sed -n '/<centerline/,/<\/centerline/p'
```

This finds everything in between `<centerline>` and `</centerline>`

I want to ignore all the cases where I have `<centerline id ="sid*" >` till closing next `</centerline>`

Basically, I want to include all the centerlines except the case where centerline is sid. 
Some of the snippets given below to be included:

```
                            <centerline id ="star12L" >
                                    <polyline>
                                            <point x="487610.06" y="2803975.46" />
                                            <point x="501348.98" y="2795594.35" />
                                    </polyline>
                            </centerline>
```

To exclude:

```
                            <centerline id ="sid12L" >
                                    <polyline>
                                            <point x="501348.98" y="2795594.35" />
                                            <point x="487610.06" y="2803975.46" />
                                    </polyline>
                            </centerline>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are parsing XML, it would be a whole lot easier to do that with an XML parser, such as `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: unfortunately, this is needed in sed as we want to process file through shell script.

Comment: You can call xmlstalet from a shell script just like you can call sed from a shell script. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (including your target strings in-context) and expected output for us to be able to help you. Make sure to cover all your worst-case scenario use cases (nested target delimiters, multiple delimiters on a line, delimiters within comments, delimiters within strings, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the XML file looks something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <centerline id="star12L">
    <polyline>
      <point x="487610.06" y="2803975.46"/>
      <point x="501348.98" y="2795594.35"/>
    </polyline>
  </centerline>
  <centerline id="sid12L">
    <polyline>
      <point x="501348.98" y="2795594.35"/>
      <point x="487610.06" y="2803975.46"/>
    </polyline>
  </centerline>
  <centerline id="star12R">
    <polyline>
      <point x="487610.06" y="2803975.46"/>
      <point x="501348.98" y="2795594.35"/>
    </polyline>
  </centerline>
</root>
```

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) would be able to parse out the two `centerline` nodes that does not have an `id` attribute starting with the string `sid`:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//centerline[starts-with(@id,"sid") = false]' -nl file.xml
<centerline id="star12L">
    <polyline>
      <point x="487610.06" y="2803975.46"/>
      <point x="501348.98" y="2795594.35"/>
    </polyline>
  </centerline><centerline id="star12R">
    <polyline>
      <point x="487610.06" y="2803975.46"/>
      <point x="501348.98" y="2795594.35"/>
    </polyline>
  </centerline>
```

The [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query `//centerline[starts-with(@id,"sid") = false]` means "match every `centerline` whose `id` attribute does not start with the string `sid`, anywhere in the document".  With `-c` on the `xmlstarlet` command line, we request a copy of the nodes matched by the query.

---

Just to show that `xmlstarlet` is slightly more powerful than just extracting things between tags:

To get the `x` and `y` values of the `point` nodes in those `centerline` structures (prefixed by the appropriate `centerline` `id`):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//centerline[starts-with(@id,"sid") = false]/polyline/point' \
                    -v 'concat(../../@id, ":", @x, ",", @y)' -nl file.xml
star12L:487610.06,2803975.46
star12L:501348.98,2795594.35
star12R:487610.06,2803975.46
star12R:501348.98,2795594.35
```

The `-m` makes `xmlstarlet` only *match* the given nodes (the `polyline/point` nodes under the non-excluded `centerline` nodes), while the following `-v` query gets values composed through `concat()`.  The `concat()` concatenates ("joins") the strings we'd like to get for each matched `point` node (`../../@id` refers to the `id` attribute in the `centerline` node).